# Apache poi xwpf converter Getting Java .outof memory in websphere server at time of deployment

Tags: apache-poi, websphere

I am working with Apache poi xwpf converter. It is working fine in local environment with tomacat ...but while deploying in websphere server, getting javaout of memory error. Already I increased the size of memory to 2048. I am getting error at the time of deployment. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Then the maximum Java heap size is not big enough. Do comparing `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` on your local environment with websphere environment.

Comment: Memory size in server 2048 mb

Comment: Your comment seems to say: 2048 MByte **must** be enough. Well, it seems not. And I have suggested to **compare** `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` on your local environment with websphere environment.  So what is it on your local environment?

Comment: Did you add memory to the system but not increase the JVM's heap size?